# Comparing the code in methods from two classes

Tags: python

For two different classes, I would like to compare the methods to see if they are the same.

I would like the code to identify that `func1` is the same and `func2` is different.

```
class A:
    def func1(self):
        return 1
    def func2(self):
        return 2

class B:
    def func1(self):
        return 1
    def func2(self):
        return 1000
```

My approach, which is not working, has been:

```
# get a list of the functions in each
a_funcs, b_funcs = dir(A), dir(B)
all_funcs = set(a_funcs).union(b_funcs)
all_funcs_no_builtins = [f for f in all_funcs if not f.startswith('__')]

# compare the methods
equal_funcs = defaultdict(list)
for f in list(all_funcs_no_builtins):
    if ((f in a_funcs) and (f in b_funcs)):
        a_code = getattr(A, f) 
        b_code = getattr(B, f) 
        if a_code == b_code:
            equal_funcs['same'].append(f)
        else:
            equal_funcs['different'].append(f)
    else:
        equal_funcs['different'].append(f)

# summarize
print("Total number of methods:", len(all_funcs_no_builtins))   # 2
print("Number that are the same:", len(equal_funcs['same']))    # 0
print("Same:", equal_funcs['same'])                             # []
print("Different:", equal_funcs['different'])         # ['func1', 'func2']
```

I also tried using `.__code__.co_code` but no luck... halp?

Comment: It seems that functions, as Python objects, don't define a useful equality operator (and presumably default to `is`). Since they're different objects, that will always be `False`.

Comment: Deciding whether two functions are equivalent is undecidable in the formal sense. The only thing you could do is call each function on every possible argument and see if the return value is the same. That's assuming each call *does* return, rather than getting stuck in an infinite loop, and ignores the possibility of side effects that could be different between two calls.

Answer (score -1):

An inelegant but effective solution is to:

1. Parse the modules with readlines()
2. Find the method names looking for lines with 'def '
3. Find the line numbers where the method start
4. Put all the lines between method names in a list
5. Compare the lists associated with each method with functools.reduce(lambda x, y : x and y, map(lambda p, q: p == q, f1, f2), True)

Comment: That just checks if two functions have the same textual representation, not if they are the same function. `def f(x): return x` and `def f(y): return y` are the same function, but would not be recognized as such by this solution. Aside from that, you can just write `all(x == y for x, y in zip(f1, f2))`.

Comment: All I needed was textual equivalence but I would love to see the solution to what you are mentioning!